# Custom stack class in java, inherited from Stack, always remains empty

Tags: java, inheritance, stack

I have inherited a class Tables from Java Stack class. 
I have overridden push and pop methods this class of mine.
Somehow, on every push , nothing gets added to the stacks showing size() always zero. Please advice me with all that might have gone wrong.
Attaching code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Stack;


class Tables extends Stack<Integer>{
boolean full;
int tabCount;
int cleanCount;
Stack<Integer> stack;
public Tables(int n){
    tabCount = n;
    stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    full = false;
    cleanCount = 0;
}
@Override
public synchronized Integer pop() {
    full = false;
    return super.pop();
}
@Override
public Integer push(Integer item) {
    System.out.println(" PushStats : "+stack.size()+" "+tabCount +"  " + stack.isEmpty());
    if(stack.size() == tabCount-1)
    {
        full = true;
    }
    cleanCount ++;
    return super.push(item);
 }
}

public class Main1{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
    int n,m,t;
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    t = Integer.parseInt( bReader.readLine());//Test Cases
    for(int test = 0 ; test <t ; test++){
        String holder = bReader.readLine();
        String[] temp = holder.trim().split(" ");
        n = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);//Tables
        m = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);//Orders
        holder = bReader.readLine();
        temp = holder.trim().split(" ");
        Integer[] orders = new Integer[m];
        for(int i =0; i<m ; i++){
            orders[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
        }
        process(n,m,orders);
    }
 }


private static void process(int n, int m, Integer[] orders) {
   Tables tables = new Tables(n);
   for(Integer order : orders){
        System.out.println("  Order from :"+order+". Stack status :full =  "+tables.full);

        if(tables.search(order) == -1){
            if(tables.full){
                System.out.println("Popped out: "+tables.pop());
            }
            tables.push(order);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Result : "+ tables.cleanCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: some code please....

Comment: You overridden the `push` and `pop` methods, so you need to post those ones if you want us to be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: i bet you forgot to call `super.push(T)` and `super.pop()` in overriden methods.

Comment: So you want us to help you by guessing. Good. Add an ``i++`` in line 3 please and tell us if it helps.

Comment: My apologies, missed to add code. Added, Please have a look now.

Comment: tabCount is a kind of limit over size of stack. I supply this when I instantiate  the stack  as follows : 
    Tables tables = new Tables(n);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've extended `Stack`, thus inheriting all its functionality, having some access to internal fields etc. Yet you also create a `Stack` instance in your constructor and keep it as a field. Some of your methods delegate to that instance, whereas others call methods on `super`.

Remove the `Stack<Integer> stack;` line and make every line that references it use the inherited fields, methods or do a super call.

You've confused two approaches here: delegation versus inheritance. Your class **is** a `Stack`, so likely it won't need to **hold** another stack.

Comment: Stupid mistake I made. Yeah, merged 2 different approaches. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CKing It's a tricky situation. I prefer just a comment, since people new to the site aren't always fully aware of the proper way of doing things. Immediate downvotes or closing could scare them away, while with some positive encouragement they might end up valuable members of the community. SO has something of a learning curve, and I remember that there used to be more patience and far less closing. Of course, some questions are clearly beyond saving. This one just needed an edit to include the code and then a bit of reading.